# Auto update slug field in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, slug

I have a simple blog where the post model contains a slug field that is prefilled with the post title. I would like to know how to get this slug updated in the background when the user updates a post title in the viewUpdate:

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

]

views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'tags']
```

I assume I should add something else to view.py in order to have the slug updated but after hours googling it, I could not find it.

Please let me know if you need more information. It is quite a simple question so I am not sure if I should provide anything else.

Comment: Change `self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.title)` to `self.slug = slugify(self.title)`

Comment: That worked and now I understand that save() in models.py is activated when the post is updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `save`method to:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    # …

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That being said, it is not per se a good idea to change the slug. A slug is usually used in a URL. That thus means that if a URL for a `Post` is for example bookmarked by a user, and later the title changes, then that URL will no longer work. Terefore a slug is usually something that should not be modified (often). In fact in most *content management systems (CMS)*, the slug does not change, and you can look at the URL to see the *original* title of the article.